# What is wrong with this line? Using Accelerometer in Cocos2d Framework

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

For some reason I am getting the error on the following line:

```
float accelX = acceleration.x * kFilterFactor + (1- kFilterFactor)*prevX;
```

I get the following message:

```
error: expected ')' before ';' token
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is not in this line. Try to put it

```
float32 accelX = 0;
```

and check if the error is gone. If not - the error is not in this line.

Answer (score 0):

check the previous line i think you didn't put a ; in that line